# Angular 2: exporting an export into a component file

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 2 app, I have a `settings.js` file with various exports that I want to use throughout the application:

```
exports.httpPort = 9000;
exports.httpsPort = 1435;
exports.segmentID = 1;
```

I want to export some of these into my ts component file `query.component.ts`, but I'm at a loss on what the correct syntax to do so is.

I see that many .js files have something along the lines of

```
var settings = require('../../settings');
```

which grabs the settings file and then

```
settings.dbConfig
```

Which calls the export, but it doesn't work on my component file.

This is my project file structure:

component.ts
- `project/web/src/app/component.ts`
-Place where I want to import an export from settings.js.

settings.js - `project/server/settings.js`
-File where I want to make the export.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

In the component class you can do:

```
...
import {httpPort} from "../../../server/settings.js"
...
```